# Template strings python 2.5 error

Tags: python

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from string import Template

s = Template('$x, go home $x')
s.substitute(x='lee')

print s
```

error i get is

```
<string.Template object at 0x81abdcc>
```

desired results i am looking for is : lee, go home lee

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to look  at the return value of `substitute`. It gives you the string with substitutions performed.

```
print s.substitute(x='lee')
```

The template object itself (`s`) is not changed. This gives you the ability to perform multiple substitutions with the same template object.

Answer (score 3):

You're not getting an error: you're getting exactly what you're asking for -- the template itself.  To achieve your desired result,

```
print s.substitute(x='lee')
```

Templates, like strings, are **not** mutable objects: any method you call on a template (or string) can never alter that template -- it can only produce a separate result which you can use.  This, of course, applies to the `.substitute` method.  You're calling it, but ignoring the result, and then printing the template -- no doubt you expect the template itself to be somehow altered, but that's just not how it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
print s.substitute(x='lee')
```